# Parameterized Instantiations and Module Instantiations

Tags: verilog

Is instantiations used above are very much similar to instantiation used in C++?I am new to verilog, yet in the stage of learning it.Like we used a instance of class in C++ at various places, so is it similar to using parametric and module instantiation?
like

```
//Module Defination
module and4(a,b,c);
   input[3:0] a,b;
   output[3:0] c;
   assign c=a&b;
   endmodule
//Module Instantiations
wire[3:0]in1,in2;
wire[3:0]o1,o2;
and4(in1,in2,o1);
and4(.c(o2),.a(in1),.b(in2));
```

so with the first view it is clear that we are using different instance of and4 to make different objects as we do in C++, but i am still doubtful that what i am thinking is wrong or right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Verilog if you instantiate a module twice you are telling your synthesis tool to actually create two separate circuits. You could imagine a synthesis tool that works by picking out actual 7400-series logic gates and robotically placing them on a breadboard, and hooking up wires between them.

In your case, the tool would actually pick out a 7408 quad AND chip, and wire up two of its gates according to the nets you assigned.

In the case of simulation, of course, you're just telling the simulator to simulate a circuit with two AND gates, rather than build an actual circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Two objects in C++ are physically two regions in memory of some microprocessor system. Two instances of modules in Verilog are two packs of logic gates and flip-flops with separate connections to the outside world. It's like comparing Sunday to a blue color, are they similar? How would you answer? :)

Try to forget any comparisons between "normal" programming languages (C/C++/Java etc) and HDLs -> hardware description languages (verilog, VHDL). The former are supposed to be executed sequentially on microprocessor, the latter are implemented in hardware (as logic gates, registers, flip-flops, RAM blocks and many more).

The concepts are **so much different** that it's pointless to compare them. If you try thinking of Verilog code in terms of C++, then it will give you a lot of headaches.

Read carefully some good book on Verilog/VHDL, everything should be explained :) Good luck!